Алгоритм Беллмана-Форда

его можно использовать как для ориентированного так и для неориентированного графа?
в алгоритме Деикстры есть такое понятие как 'посещенная вершина',то есть если от вершины б к вершине а есть путь,но вершина а уже просмотренная - мы игнорируем путь от вершины б к вершине а и смотрим какой еще есть путь от вершины б. Есть ли такое в алгоритме Беллмана-Форда? если в рамках одной итерации мы уже ходили от вершины а к вершине б, то перейдя к вершине б мы проходимся от вершины b к вершине а?



Да. 2. Нет.  Просто прочтите описание алгоритма...

